# Equals and NullPointerException

Tags: groovy

```
@Test
public void testDoc()
{

   String a1 = "123"
   String b1 = null;

   String a2 = null
   String b2 = "456";

   boolean westId1 =
   (a1 == b1) || ((a1 != null)&& b1.equals(a1));
   println westId1

   boolean westId2 =
   (a2 == b2) || ((a2 != null)&& b2.equals(a2));
   println westId2


}
```

Why don't I get a NPE on b1.equals(a1) ? when b1 is null ?

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your example code, e.g. `println westId1`.  Right now it's hard to know whether the problem is in your question or the code you're really using.

Comment: You should add the groovy tag to this question then

Answer (score 3):

This is groovy, so you're into the wonderful world of `NullObject`

If you do this:

```
b = null
println b.getClass().name
```

It will print:

```
'org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject'
```

So `b` is an instance of `NullObject`. And `NullObject` has [an `equals` method](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/NullObject.java#L80) defined as:

```
public boolean equals(Object to) {
    return to == null;
}
```

So this is why you don't get the NPE.  Short circuiting rules do apply to logical statements such as this, but the statements in the question do not get short circuited, the equals just gets handled by Groovy.

Try it out:

```
println null.equals( 4 ) // prints 'false'
```

Answer (score 1):

You do get a NPE at `b1.equals(a1)`, because your `b1` is `null` & `null.anyMethod()` would throw that exception.

Had your `a1` been `null` too, then you wouldn't have got the `NPE`, because of the `&&` operator, which wouldn't evaluate the rest of the condition, once it has encountered a `false`.

The `||` needs a `true` and the `&&` needs a `false` to short-circuit!

See this to learn more about this concept called, [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

**Update:-** For your case, it going to be like this:-

```
boolean westId1 = (a1==null && b1==null) || (a1!=null && b1!=null && a1.equals(b1));
```

You can always simplify it, but I gave the condition based on your requirement, so that it would help you understand better!

Comment: So how would you change this conditional check to evaluate to true only when the the string are both null or both non-null and equal ?

Comment: Check my update! I've framed the condition, exactly based on your words, adding the `AND/OR` in the exact places as mentioned in your sentence!

Comment: @Phoenix: `a1 == null ? a2 == null : a1.equals(a2)`

Comment: but a1==b1 should take care of returning true when null

Comment: Patashu, if a1 is null and a2 isnt what does your xpression return ?

Comment: @Phoenix - check my condition and understand how it works! You can later take up `Patashu's` expression for your actual usage, as its very simplified!

Comment: @R.J You don't get a NPE with Groovy in this instance, see my answer

Comment: @tim_yates - If you see the revision history of the question, when I'd posted the answer, the question had just the `java` tag attached to it! It was changed later, to `groovy` and stuffs!

Comment: @R.J Yeah, I know, it was an awful original question :-/